# count the ocurrences of substrings

Tags: c++

I've a task to count the occurrences of sub string in a char String. I write this code but on certain inputs output is wrong. like string is "hassana" and sub is "as" then it outputs 2 ...some one plz help me

```
int CharString :: countOccurenceOf(const char* substr)
{
    int count = 0;
    bool find = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        if(cstr[i] == substr[0])
        {
            int x = i;
            int c = 1;
            find = true;
            while ( substr[c] != '\0' && find == true && (x+1) < size1)
            {
                if(cstr [x+1] != substr[c])
                {
                    find = false;
                }
                c++;
                x++;
            }
            if (find == true)
            {
                count++;
                i = i + c-1;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Got some Solution.....is that okay?

```
int CharString :: countOccurenceOf(const char* substr)
{
int len = 0;

if ( substr != '\0')
{
    while( substr[len] != '\0')
        len++;
}
int count = 0;
bool find = false;

for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
{
    if(cstr[i] == substr[0])
    {
        int x = i;
        int c = 1;
        find = true;
        while ( substr[c] != '\0' && find == true && (x+1) < size1)
        {
            if(cstr [x+1] != substr[c])
            {
                find = false;
            }
            c++;
            x++;
        }
        if (find == true && c == len)
        {
            count++;
            i = i + c-1;
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

}

Comment: I used to use something like this as an interview question, actually.

Comment: Well that is just a Class Task. @RobP

Comment: this doesn't seem to be C++, but more C with some (very minor C++ features). Perhaps re-tag? Also: `size1` is not defined.

Comment: That is c++ and you will say cstr is not defined.....actually these are private class members here is only a functon.

Comment: Leave the question here for future programmers to learn from.

Comment: Because you chose to destroy your post after being warned about it, I've locked this from additional edits. Please don't deface your questions after you've received answers. Also, please don't insult people in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're breaking automatically if x+1 < size1. If the first character of the substring matches the last character of the main string, then this will automatically break and "find" will still be set to true so you'll increment matches by 1. There are numerous ways to change your code to fix this problem; hopefully you can find one now that you know what the problem is.

Comment: thanks man, but actually i know the problem. and need a solution.

Comment: hey can you let me know.....now what is the status.....is it fine...if you found a glitch please tell me ....want to improve...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming cstr is your class internal string:

```
int CharString :: countOccurenceOf(const char* substr)
{
    int occurrencies = 0;
    unsigned char* s = cstr;
    while (s) {
        if (strstr(s,substr)) { occurrencies++; s+= strlen(substr); }
        else s++;
    }
    return occurrencies;
}
```

Comment: Well we are not allowed to use library functions. So, thanks but problem is unsolved.

Comment: *Well we are not allowed to use library functions* WTF is this? The standard library is part of the language standard: you cannot use the language without its library.

Comment: @Walter: Sure you can.  Well, about 98% of the language.  No `typeid` operator.  And don't do a very few things that have terrible consequences anyway, like throwing an exception precluded by an function throw specification, or throw an exception from a destructor, since either of those will lead to `std::terminate()`.  The `new` and `delete` operators will default to using stuff from the standard library, but providing your own allocators is allowed.

Comment: Hmm, did you try to run it without linking against the C++ standard library?

Comment: @Walter: I have written C++ programs that use the `/NODEFAULTLIB` linker option.  So yes.

Comment: if you can't use the stdlib you should still replicate its functionalities in my opinion. Rewriting strlen and strstr is very simple.... next time please specify you can't use it....